# Data not storing in database from php page

Tags: php, mysql

Why is my code not storing data in the database? I have removed all errors that occurred.

```
<html><body>    
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db="sample";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$db);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    echo "error";
}
echo "Connected successfully";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){$Name=$_POST['name'];$age=$_POST‌​['age'];}

$sql = "INSERT INTO input1 (Name,age) VALUES (Name,age)";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  Age:<br>
  <input type="text" name="age">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Why do you have `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` twice?

Comment: In fact, we need the errors. Post them in your question

Comment: gettting any errors???

Comment: `ql = "INSERT INTO input1 (Name,age) VALUES (Name,age)";` hard coded not variables? strings need quotes

Comment: @YanetPedraza I think "removed all errors" means he fixed all the things that were causing error messages.

Comment: `Name` should be `$Name` and `age` should be `$age`, in your query... but you reallly should parameterize that.

Comment: Also please don't duplicate your content to meet the limit restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the variables as the values to insert into the DB. You should use a prepared statement.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO input1 (Name, age) VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $Name, $age);
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
}
```

Also, all this code should be inside the `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` block. Otherwise you'll try to insert empty variables into the database when the user hasn't submitted the form yet.